# How do I get rid of this open-close feature on Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

[image]

In the highlighted part, if I press that downward arrow between line 66 and "def", I get
[image]

How do I get rid of this feature on Spyder?
Please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is code folding that you want removed.

[image: code folding]